# Aurelia bundling not overwriting on bundle

Tags: aurelia

When I try to create an aurelia bundle and one already exists, I get an error basically saying it failed because a file already exists.  The problem is that my `force:true` is set.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
aureliaBundle = require('aurelia-bundler').bundle;

var aureliaBundleConfig = {
    "force": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "configPath": "js/config.js",
    "bundles": {
        "js/aurelia-bundle.min": {
            "includes": [
                "[js/**/*.js]",
                "Templates/**/*.html!text"
            ],
            "options": {
                "inject": true,
                "minify": true,
                "depCache": false
            }
        },
        "js/vendor-bundle": {
            "includes": [
                "lib/github/components/jquery@2.2.4",
                "lib/github/signalr/bower-signalr@2.2.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-framework@1.0.0-rc.1.0.2",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-http-client@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-kendoui-bridge@0.11.8",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-templating@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
                "lib/npm/aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0"
            ],
            "options": {
                "inject": true,
                "minify": true,
                "depCache": false
            }
        }
    }
};

gulp.task('bundle:aurelia', function () {
    return aureliaBundle(aureliaBundleConfig);
});
```

Comment: that's odd, the skeletons usually clean dist folder before generating new files. Which skeleton are you using?

Comment: I am using the ASPNET pack but slightly altered.  I don't put everything in the same folder.

Comment: We will need a lot more information. If you can't provide actual code, at least provide the source of the template you're using. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the question with the included code.